# Cached version of child theme css loading after updated css file?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, child-theming

I'm building a wp child theme of ThemeGrill's ColorMag. When I load the page, my child theme css file is loaded, but there is also a file called style.css?ver=5.3.2 loaded after it. When I look at the code under elements in the dev tools, it appears to be a cached version of my style.css file.

I've deleted the child theme folder and reuploaded all of my files but I see the same result. I also have wp-cache level set to 0

Also I should note, I'm new to wp and couldn't figure out how to enqueue the child theme properly, so style.css is loaded via an href in my header.php. my functions.php looks like this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
```

Again, I'm new so any best practices you have would be much appreciated!

Site is [here](https://thedumprunner.com/).

Comment: Always use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` when you want resources from your child theme.

Comment: I just tried changing my functions.php to ` <?php function my_theme_enqueue_styles() { wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ); wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('parent-style') ); } add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' ); ?> ` but I'm getting the same result